# graph api get public events with rails/koala works only for some sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, koala-gem

This is my code

```
Koala.config.api_version = 'v2.3'
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new 'app_id', 'app_secret'
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new @oauth.get_app_access_token

@events = @graph.get_object('141991029192409/events')
```

which works fine. If I try to fetch the events from another site like

```
@events = @graph.get_object('161335993890217/events')
```

I get this error

> GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported get request.
>   Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [HTTP 400]

Comment: That page is likely restricted in some way (alcohol related content, age, location) – and that means you need to use a _user_ access token instead of the app access token.

Comment: Thx for the hint :) With an user access token it works fine.. if you post your comment as an answer i will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is likely restricted in some way (alcohol related content, age, location) – and that means you need to use a user access token instead of the app access token. (Or a page access token, if you have admin control over that page.)

With a user access token, Facebook uses the information about that user to determine whether or not they are allowed to see the page. An app access token could be used by “anyone”, and therefor can not be used to access such restricted pages.

Comment: just wanted to add that a page access token is working too to get the data plus it is possible to get a page token that never expires :) so that seems to be a good replacement to grab public data server side

Comment: Yes, of course, for pages that you have admin access to that  is the preferred way.